# OpenLayer v4.2.0 showing error 'Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy'

Tags: javascript, javafx, openlayers

Our's is a JavaFx application which utilizes the browser capability of WebView to render webpages. We were able to perform upcalls from JavaScript to JavaFX and vice versa. WebConsoleListener is added to log messages or error thrown from wepage.

To show few Map functionalities like coordinate selection, distance calculation etc in JavaFX application, we created a webpage and wrote the necessary javascript required utilizing OpenLayer v4.2.0 API. Everything worked in browser ( of course after removing upcalls to JavaFx) as well as in JavaFx application.

However when the application is deployed to customer, its logging error 'Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy' and the map tiles were not loaded. Customer is located in a different geographic location (Japan) and we dont have access to their machines.

Their is a 'crossOrigin' property for 'ol.source.OSM' and as mentioned in documentation its value remains 'anonymous'. We were able to reproduce  a similar kind of issue when we set its value to 'use-credentials'.

Below is the code related to map rendering. If required we can post entire code which is related to adding geometry and various event handling
(depending on user action overlays were removed or added).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="ol.js"></script>

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(
                )
    });

    var coordinateOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
        }),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 7,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: '#d12b19'
                })
            })
        })
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, coordinateOverlay],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [-11000000, 4600000],
            zoom: 5
        })
    });

 var features = new ol.Collection();

    var distanceOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({ features: features }),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#d12b19',
                width: 4
            }),
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 7,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'red'
                })
            })
        })
    });
```

Please help if anyone know the reason for this issue.

EDIT
Client is behind proxy. [ IMHO, Looks irrelevant here, as the request is already placed.]

Comment: could you find any solutions/?

Comment: You only need a cross origin setting if you need to access the canvas.  If not set `crossOrigin: null` (or use the .XYZ constructor which has no default instead of .OSM which defaults to anonymous).